# How can I omit the regression intercept from my results table in stargazer

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

I run a regression of the type

```
model <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3, weights = wei, data=data1)
```

and then create my table

```
,t <- stargazer(model, omit="x2", omit.labels="x1")
```

but I haven't found a way to omit the intercept results from the table. I need it in the regression, yet I don't want to show it in the table.

Is there a way to do it through stargazer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't your dataset, but typing `omit = c("Constant", "x2")` should work.

As a reproducible example (stargazer 5.2)

```
stargazer::stargazer(
  lm(Fertility ~ . , 
     data = swiss), 
  type = "text", 
  omit = c("Constant", "Agriculture"))
```

Edit: Add in `omit.labels`

```r
mdls <- list(
  m1 = lm(Days ~ -1 + Reaction, data = lme4::sleepstudy),
  m2 = lm(Days ~ Reaction, data = lme4::sleepstudy),
  m3 = lm(Days ~ Reaction + Subject, data = lme4::sleepstudy)
)

stargazer::stargazer(
  mdls, type = "text", column.labels = c("Omit none", "Omit int.", "Omit int/subj"),
  omit = c("Constant", "Subject"),
  omit.labels = c("Intercept", "Subj."),
  keep.stat = "n")
#> 
#> ==============================================
#>                     Dependent variable:       
#>              ---------------------------------
#>                            Days               
#>              Omit none Omit int. Omit int/subj
#>                 (1)       (2)         (3)     
#> ----------------------------------------------
#> Reaction     0.015***  0.027***    0.049***   
#>               (0.001)   (0.003)     (0.004)   
#>                                               
#> ----------------------------------------------
#> Intercept       No        No          No      
#> Subj.           No        No          No      
#> ----------------------------------------------
#> Observations    180       180         180     
#> ==============================================
#> Note:              *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note the table should read. This appears to be a bug (stargazer 5.2.2).

```
#> Intercept       No        Yes       Yes    
#> Subj.           No        No        Yes
```

Comment: This works if you don't want to use `omit` for its other purpose of e.g. collapsing and naming fixed effects. For example, it fails if you also pass `omit.labels=c("ag")`.

Comment: @MaxGhenis `omit` and `omit.labels` must be the same length, so `omit.labels = c("Intercept", "ag")` will work.

Comment: But then it'll show the intercept. `c(NULL, "ag")` throws an error. I don't think there's a way to use this to hide the intercept while showing fixed effects.

Comment: @MaxGhenis The purpose of `omit.labels` is to indicate "whether variables have been omitted from a given model", in my mind this includes the intercept. Unfortunately there appears to be a bug in `stargazer` at the moment (as you have noticed!). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38355337/4241780.

Answer (score 3):

I got a way of doing it. It is not the most clever way, but works.

I just change the omit command to a keep command. In my example above:

```
library(stargazer) 

model <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3, weights = wei, data=data1)
t <- stargazer(model, keep=c("x1","x3"), omit.labels="x1")
```

However, it's not an efficient way when you have many variables you want to keep in the regression table